# Can't find file Resource using Spring Batch on Linux system

Tags: linux, spring-batch

I'm running Spring Batch job on Linux (works fine on Windows).  It's a simple file existence check but I am unable to get the system to find the path/file when it definitely exists.  Does Spring's Resource class somehow automatically know when it's run on Linux or Windows?  Is there something else I can do

My job definition

```
    <batch:job id="vendorGoalsJob" restartable="true">
            <batch:step id="checkStartFileExists" next="readHeaderFiles">
                <batch:tasklet ref="startFileExistsTasklet" />
            </batch:step>
     more steps....
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="startFileExistsTasklet"
        class="com.blah.blah.StartFileExistsTasklet"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="/di/global/Users/my filename with blanks.txt" />
    </bean>
```

The tasklet class:

```
package com.blah.blah;

import static java.lang.String.format;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class StartFileExistsTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StartFileExistsTasklet.class);
    private Resource resource; 

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        if (!resource.isReadable()) {
            logger.info(format("Resource %s not found.",  resource.getFilename()));
            chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setTerminateOnly();
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }


}
```

...And I always get the 'not found message':

```
2013-09-26 15:47:09,342 handleStep Executing step: [checkStartFileExists]                                           (SimpleStepHandler.java:133) 
2013-09-26 15:47:09,352 execute Resource vendor-goal-trigger.txt not found.                                      
2013-09-26 15:47:09,361 isInterrupted Step interrupted through StepExecution
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default RessourceLoader used by Spring loads from the classpath if the protocol is not specified in the ressource URL.

```
/**
 * Default implementation of the {@link ResourceLoader} interface.
 * Used by {@link ResourceEditor}, and serves as base class for
 * {@link org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext}.
 * Can also be used standalone.
 *
 * <p>Will return a {@link UrlResource} if the location value is a URL,
 * and a {@link ClassPathResource} if it is a non-URL path or a
 * "classpath:" pseudo-URL.
 *
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @since 10.03.2004
 * @see FileSystemResourceLoader
 * @see org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
 */
public class DefaultResourceLoader implements ResourceLoader { ... }
```

You may try using the `file:` prefix:

```
<property name="resource" value="file:/di/global/Users/my filename with blanks.txt"/>
```

Comment: Bingo!  That was it.  Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.  And, your explanation helps me further understand what Spring is doing too.

Comment: np, you can find the behavior described here: org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader. This class is sometimes useful to use in your own code